# What is the terminology for the brightest point on a plane

Tags: brdf

Given a plane, assuming that view direction and light direction are both fixed, there must be point which is the brightest point on that plane(where half vector equals to the normal vector).What is the terminology for that point?(Assuming we are using GGX)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there's a specific standardized term for that point, but the general bright area is called the "highlight" or "specular highlight", and so the brightest point on it could be called the highlight peak or highlight center.